# Recyclerview : how to mix some post with image and no image?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to display in same recycle-view which is some post have image and some post does not have images.

I can retrieve all the post with image and non-image,
but i want to change the size of the post when the user only post text(no image).

I expect the output like twitter feed..some post with image and without image have their own size.

Comment: You can show one image view when there is no image you can hide it else show

Comment: You Can set Visibility to Gone or Visible for the Imageview depending on the condition.

Comment: What you want to do is to create an adapter with multiple view types.

Possible duplication of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Comment: I would suggest to use default image which will override if no image is available.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type/51153083#51153083

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple way to achieve this scenario is, All you have to do is create a view with both image and text, in recycler adapter check if image data is available make visibility of image visible else Image visibility gone.

Second Approach for this to make multiple view for `RecyclerView`.

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder called");        
        ContentItem item = mContentItems.get(position);

        if(item.getName()!=null){
             holder.textName.setVisibility(View.Visible);
             holder.textName.setText(item.getName());        
        }else{
             holder.textName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

       if(item.getPreviewImageDefault()!=null){
             holder.imageIcon.setVisibility(View.Visible)        
             Picasso.with(mContext).load("file://" + item.getPreviewImageDefault()).into(holder.imageIcon);  
       }else{
             holder.imageIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE)
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is create 2 xml layouts and use ViewType in your RecyclerView.

look this [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the image when it is `ic_launcher` you could do that (suppposing that `data.getImage()` returns the id of the drawable as integer):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

   if(mItems!=null){
      AdapterData data = mItems.get(i);
      viewHolder.text.setText(data.getText());
      viewHolder.image.setImageResource(data.getImage());

      if(TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getText())){
         viewHolder.text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }else{
         viewHolder.text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }

      if(data.getImage()==R.drawable.ic_launcher){
         viewHolder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }else{
         viewHolder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, like some people have already said, is to hide/show the ImageView.

You could do that in the ViewHolder that you use for your RecyclerView.

```
class OptionalImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView image;
    private TextView text;
    // any other views you have

    public OptionalImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewIdHere);
        text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewIdHere);
        // same for any other views you have
    }

    public void bindView(Tweet tweet) {
        // This is where the magic happens
        // Note: I make the assumption that you have a class called "Tweet"
        // that has a field for "text", a field for "image" (that can be
        // null if there's no image), and any other necessary fields.

        text.setText(tweet.getTweetText());
        if (tweet.hasImage() /* function that returns whether or not there is an image */) {
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            image.setImageBitmap(tweet.getImage()); // or however you are setting the image
        } else {
            // else just make the image invisible
            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView supports different viewTypes (layouts) which is the proper way in such scenario. E.g.,

```
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {

  override fun getViewTypes(position:Int) =
    if (mydata[position].hasImage) return R.layout.mylayout_with_image
    else R.layout.mylayout_no_image;

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewType:Int, parent:ViewGroup) : MyViewHolder =
    // here viewType = layout id
    MyViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(viewType, parent))

  override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder:MyViewHolder, position:Int) {
    // guaranteed viewHolder.itemView is the view you want for that position
  }

}
```

Comment: `(mydata[position].hasImage)` i have user image and post image..